# add dot before first integer in all lines

Tags: regex, awk, sed, text-editor

I have lines like

**Input:**

```
abcd1234  
bdfghks4506  
agfdch6985
```

I would like to add "." before the first integer in line, how do I do it?

**Output:**

```
abcd.1234  
bdfghks.4506  
agfdch.6985
```

Comment: Are you just asking a regex, or programming code?

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -i 's/[[:digit:]]/.&/' file
```

If there is a digit in a line, put a `.` before it.

N.B. To put a `.` before every digit in a file use:

```
sed -i 's/[[:digit:]]/.&/g' file
```

Comment: I got chinese and symbols appeared between string and integer, instead "."
Most likely because of the encoding

Answer (score 1):

The most strict command for your case would be

```
sed -E -i 's/([a-z])([1-9])/\1\.\2/' file.txt
```

`-E` Use extended regex
   `-i ''` Replace in file (instead of writing to output)

This will match any example you provided

Comment: The 'prefixed by a-z' wasn't actually part of the requirement, though. It's entirely possible the real examples can include more complex input than those simplified ones posted here. The use of [a-z] (or \w) always bothers me because it'll break on any kind of accented character. If you absolutely do need to check a prefix, `[^0-9]` seems a lot safer.

Comment: This is just what i infer from the examples. And as i said it is the strictest version that still matches all examples.

Comment: # sed -E -i ''  's/([a-z])([1-9])/\1\.\2/' isim.txt 

sed: can't read s/([a-z])([1-9])/\1\.\2/: No such file or directory

I have no idea why this happened

Comment: edited my answer for better compatibility. `-i` works a bit different in [FreeBSD and OS/X](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?sed) and in [GNU/linux](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.txt)  compare man pages for more details

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat > input.txt
abcd1234
bdfghks4506
agfdch6985
$ sed -e 's/^\([^0-9]*\)\([0-9]\)\(.*\)$/\1.\2\3/' input.txt
abcd.1234
bdfghks.4506
agfdch.6985
```

Use sed string replacement with regular expression capture groups.

1. Match the beginning of the line.
2. Start a capture group that matches any number of non-numeric characters.
3. Start a second capture group that matches a single digit.
4. Start a third capture group that matches the remainder of the line.
5. Match the end of the line.
6. Replace the entire line with the contents of the first capture group, ".", the second capture group and, finally, the third capture group.

Answer (score 1):

The function `sub` of `awk` may help,

```
$ awk 'sub(/[0-9]/,".&",$0)1' file
abcd.1234  
bdfghks.4506  
agfdch.6985
```

Brief explanation,

- `sub`: replace only the first matching substring in each line
- `&`: is replaced with the text that was actually matched (i.e. [0-9])
- Appended `1`: to print the result.

Comment: if it only replaces the first match, how will it process all lines?

Comment: @Nyerguds, it would replace the first matching substring "each line".

Comment: Ah. Your 'brief explanation' didn't specify that.

Comment: `awk` would process one line at a time, but I'll add more explanation for that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not familiar with awk / sed specifically, but a regex replace using this regex should be all you need:

Search: `(\d+.*?)$` (match everything from the first found number to the end of the line)

Replace by: `.$1` (captured group #1 prefixed by a literal `.`)

The notation of the capture group in the replace command may differ depending on the implementation. I used `$1` here, but some implementations may use `\1`.